# Is it possible to install GNS3 in Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, libraries

I tried to run the gns3 installer that I used on previous versions of Ubuntu and it worked, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The gns3 PPA currently supports only Ubuntu 22.10 and earlier because it hasn't been updated to 23.04 yet. Wait for the gns3 PPA to be updated to 23.04 or else build gns3 from source.

Comment: genial, graciaa

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

The gns3 PPA currently supports only Ubuntu 22.10 and earlier because it hasn't been updated to 23.04 yet. Wait for the gns3 PPA to be updated to 23.04 or else build gns3 from source.